# how to combine two table values to one array in vuetify

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify table with multiple values consisting of, Date,start and endtime and votername. What I am trying know is to push on button click two selected rows into one new array object. I can push already the selected rows to one array but each of them being seperate object inside my array but this is not what I want.

this is what I am getting if I push the whole array:

```
{
   "id":null,
   "date":"2021-06-18",
   "startTime":"23:00",
   "endTime":"23:30",
   "voterUniqueName":"Hasan",
   "meetingName":"hallo"
},
{
   "id":null,
   "date":"2021-06-18",
   "startTime":"23:00",
   "endTime":"23:30",
   "voterUniqueName":"Turan",
   "meetingName":"hallo"
}
```

but what I want to get is the following:

```
{ 
"voterUniqueName": "Hasan", 
"voterUniqueName2": "Turan" 
},
```

I want to simplify the two values like this two one array object.

but when I try to push the names of the array I am getting an undefined. Could someone look at my code and tell me where my mistake is?

HTML:

```
 <v-data-table
            v-model="selected"
            :headers="headers"
            :items="filterByDate"
            item-key="voterUniqueName"
            show-select
            class="elevation-1"

          >
            <template v-slot:top>
              <v-col cols="3">
              <v-select
                  :items="availableTimes"
                  item-text="date"
                  @select="filterByDate"
                  v-model="selectedDate"
                  ></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-chip-group
                    v-model="selection"
                    active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4">
                  <v-chip
                      v-for="(time, i) in dateTimeArray"
                      :key="time"
                      :value="time"
                      @click="getTimesFiltered(time)">
                    {{ time.startTime +" : "+ time.endTime }}
                  </v-chip>
                </v-chip-group>
              </v-col>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
```

script:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "MeetingAdminComponent",
  data : ()=>({
    singleSelect: false,
    selected: [],
    meetingArray: [],
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Date',
        align: 'center',
        value: 'date',
      },
      { text: 'Voter', value: 'voterUniqueName' },
      { text: 'Starttime', value: 'startTime' },
      { text: 'Endtime', value: 'endTime' },
    ],
    availableTimes: [
    ],

  }),


  methods:{
  
    pushSelected(){
      this.meetingArray.push({
        name1: this.selected.name,
        name2: this.selected.name
      })
      console.log(this.meetingArray)


    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanna achieve is something like this:

```
{ 
"voterUniqueName": "Hasan", 
"voterUniqueName2": "Turan" 
}
```

Then simply do something like this:

```js
// In your case this will be the selected items: this.selected
const voters = [
{
   "id":null,
   "date":"2021-06-18",
   "startTime":"23:00",
   "endTime":"23:30",
   "voterUniqueName":"Hasan",
   "meetingName":"hallo"
},
{
   "id":null,
   "date":"2021-06-18",
   "startTime":"23:00",
   "endTime":"23:30",
   "voterUniqueName":"Turan",
   "meetingName":"hallo"
}
]

// Create an empty object to join the items
const joinedVoters = {};
voters.forEach((voter, index) => {
  // Gets the voter position plus one for the key
  const item = index + 1; 
  // This will insert the "voterUniqueName in the position 0 of the array as the key "name1" 
  joinedVoters[`name${item}`] = voter.voterUniqueName;
})
console.log(joinedVoters)
```

For your specific case, your method should end up looking this:

```
methods:{
  
    pushSelected(){

      const newMeeting = {};

      this.selected.forEach((voter, i) => {
          const key = `name${i + 1}`;
          newMeeting[key] = voter.voterUniqueName;
      })

      this.meetingArray.push(newMeeting);
      console.log(this.meetingArray)

    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I tried this but I am getting the names as undefined. and if I do this voter.voterUniqueName, the name is undefined and it says I should generate an variable called voterUniqueName, the voter array is filled after selecting a row from the table, could it be because of that?

Comment: I just finished editing my answer to show an idea of what the method for your case should end up looking. Does it still gives you the same problem?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply I had to go sleeping due to work today, I will try this and then report back.

Comment: Hey I just tried it but am getting the error: this.meetingArray.push is not a function. Is this because meetingArray is initially empty?

Comment: You have to initialize the array as empty array ```[]``` so that you can push objects into it.